# Integral in 3 dimensions

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates, dirac-delta

I am trying to integrate

$$ \iiint  \delta(|\mathbf r| -R)\:\mathrm{d}^{3}\mathbf{r} $$

I know that $ \int f(r) \delta(r-R) d^3 \mathbf r =f(R) $, but when I try to apply this here I end up confusing myself, as I seem to have $f(r) = 1 $. So is my answer just 1? This seems wrong...

I then attempted in spherical polars giving:
$$ \iiint \delta (r-R)\delta (\theta-R)\delta (\phi-R) \:\mathrm{d}r \:\mathrm{d}\theta \:\mathrm{d}\phi $$

I am confused as to where I go from here, and how the magnitude sign in the initial integral affects the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure but I think you need to try integrating r three times.  So first integral is 1.  The second would be integral of 1.  The third integral should be a function of r.  Spherical coordinates probably need some trig functions to yield same results.

Comment: integrate r? But I dont have an r term? So integrate 1 three times, but with respect to what?

Comment: the delta dirac Is an infinite impulse at r=R and "loosely" or heuristically is \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(r) \, dr = 1.  So you integrate in all the r domain, which probably is 0 to infinity.  If you need polar angles, the angles must sweep the whole volume (sphere).  So angles are unitless from 0 to pi or 2pi, where needed.

Comment: Ok but I dont understand why the answer isn't 1. We have the formula that defines the delta function, in 3D, and it says that the answer should be f(R). But since f(r)=1, f(R)=1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the volume element in [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

$$d^3 {\mathbf r}=r^2\sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi$$

the integral factorizes to

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d^3 {\mathbf r}\delta(|\mathbf r|-R)=
\underbrace{\left(\int_0^\infty dr r^2\delta(r-R)\right)}_{\displaystyle{=R^2}}\underbrace{\left(\int_0 ^\pi d\theta \sin\theta\right)}_{\displaystyle{=\cos0-\cos\pi=2}} 
\underbrace{\left(\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \right)}_{\displaystyle{=2\pi}}=4\pi R^2.$$

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user1887919 no problem, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd r\,r^{2}\delta\pars{R - r}
\overbrace{\int\dd\Omega_{\vec{r}}}^{\ds{4\pi}} = \color{#00f}{\large 4\pi R^{2}}
$$

Comment: ?? This was posted 6 days earlier in the other answer. Are you just trying to lower the signal/noise ratio?